# does vector still exist?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
std::vector<float> someOp(void)
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<float> results;
    // some operations done to results
    return results;
}

int main(void)
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<float> &results = someOp();
}
```

Does the vector returned by someOp exist in the someOp() stack space or in the main() stack space?

I'm inclined to believe that it doesn't get copied/moved to the main() stack space since the results vector has the same address inside of both methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither, that's not valid C++ (and doesn't get compiled by g++).

It seems you're trying to store a reference to the returned `results`, but that's impossible as the returned `results` exists in the stack frame of `someOp`, and, while it will still be there just after `someOp()` returns, will get overwritten at some point in the future.

Comment: hmmm... so I guess the question is why did visual studio 2010 let me compile it? Is the standard unclear about this, or did Microsoft mess up again?

Comment: @helloworld922: VC++ has language extensions - you can turn them off with the /Za flag, but then Microsoft's own headers usually fail to compile...go figure.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't know. @Mystical's discussion below may be of greater help. I'd test but I don't think I have a VM containing Visual Studio on my laptop.

Comment: As a follow-up, would this be "safe" code in vc++? Or is it only that the compiler lets you compile it?

Comment: I'm going to assume for the meantime that VC++ will attempt to bind the `results` in main to the same as the one in `someOp`. It's perfectly possible the optimiser inlined `someOp` or did some other trickery though, or that it simply generates incorrect code. As for your question, no, it's unsafe, if even for the fact that nobody that has currently commented can decide 100% what it does.

Comment: @slugonamission: Try compiling with `/W4` (warning level 4) and `/WX` (convert warnings into errors) and see if you get any errors.

Comment: @Insilico - I'm using G++, I'm just trying to figure out what it would be trying to do internally.

Comment: VC++ 2010 implements move semantics and perfect forwarding (C++11). Is it possible the returned temporary gets converted to a local temporary by applying an appropriate constructor? Thus, the reference is to the local copy which exists in the `main` scope.

Comment: Could be, although I've not read the C++11 spec. This is going to bug me now though, so I'll try and have a look at work tomorrow when I'll have access to VC++2010.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little more complicated than that.

Yes, it is initially in the stack space of `someOp`. But since you return by value, a copy is made. So it isn't lost (yet).

However, when you store it into `vector<float> &results`, you store a reference to it. Which becomes invalid after the statement ends. The returned vector is an intermediate that is destroyed after the statement ends.

So the end result is that `vector<float> &results` becomes a dangling "pointer".

**EDIT :** (see comments)

Apparently, the code isn't supposed to compile at all. But it does in VS2010. So my answer only applies to the case where it does compile.

Comment: Returning by value does not necessarily mean a copy.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Also bad. Returning a reference to a local variable.

Comment: @Duracell: Can you clarify that comment?

Comment: Reluctantly -1 - the question's moot because the code is invalid.

Comment: @Duracell I was referring to http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/ so a `const&` wouldn't be bad.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Correct, I didn't mention anything about return value optimization.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz: Actually it does compile (at least in VC++). But you're right in that it's probably still invalid.

Comment: @Mystical: I should have said "it's not Standard C++ and doesn't compile portably".

Comment: @Mystical: The article Seth references mentions the same point, for what it's worth.

Comment: @Seth: Returning an automatic variable by const reference is still undefined behavior. What you *can* do is bind an automatic const reference to a prvalue, like `const string& s = f();` in Herb's example. Please note that `f` returns by value, *not* by const reference!

Comment: @SethCarnegie: NO. Re-read Herb Sutter's article. What you're suggesting behaves exactly like returning a non-const reference.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't compile portably - in Standard C++, you can't bind a temporary (the `std::vector<float>` returned by `someOp` in this case) to a non-const reference.

Comment: huh, interesting... visual c++ has misled me again :(

Comment: @helloworld922: It does that sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is incorrect and should be rejected, but still the question would apply to a slight modification of it, but before discussing it lets describe the following simpler program:

```
type f() {
   type x;        // [1]
   return x;      // [2]
}
int main() {
   type m = f();  // [3]
   m.const_function();
}
```

In the program above there are conceptually 3 objects, there is `x` inside `f`, the returned value that is unnamed and finally `m` inside `main`. `x` is created in [1], then copied to the returned object in [2] which finally is used to copy construct `m` in [3].

Now back to the reference case:

```
type f() {
   type x;                // [1]
   return x;              // [2]
}
int main() {
   type const & r = f();  // [3]
   r.const_function();
}
```

Conceptually, the same thing is going on. An object `x` is created at [1], and copied to the returned value in [2], now in [3] that returned value is not used to initialize `r`, but rather to initialize an unnamed object injected by the compiler. Finally, in [3] the constant reference is bound to the unnamed object. At this point, the *unnamed* object is in the context of `main`.

As of what actually happens in current compilers, the calling convention determines how the interface of the functions is implemented. The calling convention for a function that returns an object that does not fit in registers is implemented (in all compilers I know) by passing an extra hidden pointer to the function. That is, the caller (`main` in this case) reserves space in the stack and then passes a pointer to that location into the callee. This is the location where caller and callee agree that the returned object will live. This means that the caller can reserve space for `m` in the original example or for the unnamed object in the second case and pass the pointer in. This removes one of the objects from the equation as `m` (or the unnamed object) and the returned object *are* the same. The next step is performed by the compiler when processing the callee, if it can determine that `x` will be returned in all code paths, it will not create `x` in its own stack, but directly on the memory referenced by the hidden pointer. When this is done, the net effect is that there will be a single object in the program:

*`main` will acquire memory, and pass a pointer to `f`, `f` will create `x` on that memory location (which is in `main`'s stack space) and return to `main`, in the case of the `const` reference the compiler will* alias *the unnamed object by the name of the reference.*

(Note: the reference and the unnamed object are *not* the same, their types can actually differ, but the reference will be an *alias* to the unnamed object that provides a name for it)